# How can I find conjugate classes of $\mathbb Z_4$ or any$\mathbb Z_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I find conjugate classes of $\mathbb Z_2$ or any $\mathbb Z_n$?

What is the binary operation that works on these groups?

Comment: These groups are abelian... The binary operation is addition mod $n$.

Comment: Does that mean conjugate classes of Zn is {0}, {1} ....{n} ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But note that the class of $n$ is the same as the class of $0$.

Comment: @Nancy:if my group be commutative every conjugate of element or subgroups be itself.since every element commutative.suppose $H=<3>$in $\mathbb Z_6$conjugate classes of $H$ is $-gHg$ st $g\in \mathbb Z_6$ and $-4<3>4$=$\{2+3+4,2+1+4,2+2+4\}=<3>$

Answer (score 6):

The conjugacy of an element $x$ in any abelian group is just itself  since $gxg^{-1} = gg^{-1}x = x$.